# control background music from 3rd party apps ios

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there a way to control music currently playing in the background? I am able to control the native ipod application with the `MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer`, but what i basically want is the functionality of the ipod controller in the task switcher. I want to be able to control the app currently playing (next/prev). The controls in the task switcher controls spotify, pandora or any other app currently playing.

Any ideas?

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of adding another layer of abstraction to the Task Switcher would be?

Comment: My question has little or nothing to do with the task switcher itself. I want my users to be able to control their music easy instead of double click home button -> swipe -> tap next

Comment: And my comment had little to do with the task switcher.  I'm asking what the purpose of an app that does what the system does? Besides, [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMusicPlayerController/skipToNextItem) is what you're probably looking for anyhow.

Comment: I can se many use cases for this. In games, players choose whatever music-source they want, and ask for the next track without leaving the game. As for my use, I am creating a sleep timer and would like to change tracks without leaving the app. I have already looked at your link, which lets me control the native ipod music player, but not other apps like Spotify and Pandora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Make sure you are using the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback audio session, first off.  After you activate the audio session, call:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

See here for more details
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this for accepting remote control events and not sending them? To be clear, I want to skip next/previous in the app currently playing in the background (not my own).

Comment: You want to control another app that is not the iPod Music Player?  Can't be done.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the right answer to the question. This answer is about intercepting remote control events in your 3rd party apps; the question was about sending remote control events to other 3rd party apps.